# Using dynamic buffer displays empty mesh in Directx 9

Tags: dynamic, directx, buffer, mesh

I'm trying to use dynamic arrays when creating both vertex and index buffers for a mesh, like this:

```
// Create the mesh with a call to D3DXCreateMeshFVF
D3DXCreateMeshFVF(caras_a_dibujar, // NumFaces
    cantidad_de_puntos, // NumVertices
    D3DXMESH_MANAGED, // Options
    CUSTOMFVF, // FVF
    d3ddev, // pDevice
    &esfera_purete); // ppMesh

CUSTOMVERTEX* g_Vertices = NULL;   // Pointer to CUSTOMVERTEX, initialize to nothing.
g_Vertices = new CUSTOMVERTEX[cantidad_de_puntos];  // Allocate cantidad_de_puntos and save pointer in g_Vertices.

for (int n = 0; n < cantidad_de_puntos; n++) g_Vertices[n] = { puntos_unicos[n].x, puntos_unicos[n].y, puntos_unicos[n].z, { puntos_unicos[n].x, puntos_unicos[n].y, puntos_unicos[n].z }, 0.5f + atan2f(puntos_unicos[n].z, puntos_unicos[n].x) / (2 * D3DX_PI), 0.5f - asinf(puntos_unicos[n].y) / D3DX_PI };
VOID* pVertices;
// Lock the vertex buffer
esfera_purete->LockVertexBuffer(D3DLOCK_DISCARD, (void**)&pVertices);
// Copy the vertices into the buffer
memcpy(pVertices, g_Vertices, sizeof(g_Vertices));
// Unlock the vertex buffer
esfera_purete->UnlockVertexBuffer();


WORD* IndexData = NULL;   // Pointer to WORD, initialize to nothing.
IndexData = new WORD[caras_a_dibujar * 3];  // Allocate caras_a_dibujar * 3 and save pointer in IndexData.

for (int n = 0; n < caras_a_dibujar * 3; n++) IndexData[n] = indice[n];
// Prepare to copy the indices into the index buffer
VOID* IndexPtr;
// Lock the index buffer
esfera_purete->LockIndexBuffer(0, &IndexPtr);
// Copy the indices into the buffer
memcpy(IndexPtr, IndexData, sizeof(IndexData));
// Unlock the buffer
esfera_purete->UnlockIndexBuffer();


delete[] g_Vertices;  // free memory pointed to by g_Vertices.
g_Vertices = NULL;     // Clear a to prevent using invalid memory reference.
delete[] IndexData;  // free memory pointed to by IndexData.
IndexData = NULL;     // Clear a to prevent using invalid memory reference.

cantidad_faces = esfera_purete->GetNumFaces();
```

The code compiles and runs smoothly and even gives me the correct number of faces and vertices in the mesh with GetNumFaces() and GetNumVertices(), but the mesh doesn't render, it's just invisible. I'm using this kind of dynamic allocation of memory for the first time so I'm sure the problem is in the lines:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX* g_Vertices = NULL;   // Pointer to CUSTOMVERTEX, initialize to nothing.
g_Vertices = new CUSTOMVERTEX[cantidad_de_puntos];  // Allocate cantidad_de_puntos and save pointer in g_Vertices.
```

and:

```
WORD* IndexData = NULL;   // Pointer to WORD, initialize to nothing.
IndexData = new WORD[caras_a_dibujar * 3];  // Allocate caras_a_dibujar * 3 and save pointer in IndexData.
```

But, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem once. It was because the order of the indices for the face were backwards. Instead clockwise indexing, it needed counter-clockwise indexing. This means, (0,1,2) didn't work, but (0,2,1) did. I suppose it depends on how you set up the matrices and backface culling.